# How to upload files to Google Drive folder without asking (API PHP)

Tags: php, api, google-drive-api

This script wants to 'connect me' after a while.
I am using it for people to upload a file to my Google Drive (from a form).
I was thinking it wasn't needed to connect again...I like it automatic.
What I'm I doing wrong?

I'm using the [Github Lib](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)
Can somebody help me?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

 include_once "google-drive-client-php-master/examples/templates/base.php";
session_start();
set_include_path("google-drive-client-php-master/src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'google-drive-client-php-master/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'google-drive-client-php-master/src/Google/Http/MediaFileUpload.php';
require_once 'google-drive-client-php-master/src/Google/Service/Drive.php';

$client_id = '**********';
$client_secret = '**********';
$redirect_uri = '**********';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['upload_token ']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['upload_token']) && $_SESSION['upload_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  }
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

/************************************************
  If we're signed in then lets try to upload our
  file.
 ************************************************/
    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

$chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
$filepath = "data/test.txt"; 
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setTitle('Alie'); 
$file->setDescription('A test document'); 
$file->setMimeType('text/plain'); 

//Set the parent folder

$parentId='**********';
$parent = new Google_ParentReference(); 
$parent->setId($parentId); 
$file->setParents(array($parent));

  // Call the API with the media upload, defer so it doesn't immediately return.
  $client->setDefer(true);
  $request = $service->files->insert($file);

  // Create a media file upload to represent our upload process.
  $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
      $client,
      $request,
      'text/plain',
      null,
      true,
      $chunkSizeBytes
  );
  $media->setFileSize(filesize($filepath));

  // Upload the various chunks. $status will be false until the process is
  // complete.
  $status = false;
  $handle = fopen($filepath, "rb");
  while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
    $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
    $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
  }

  // The final value of $status will be the data from the API for the object
  // that has been uploaded.
  $result = false;
  if ($status != false) {
    $result = $status;
  }

  fclose($handle);
}
echo pageHeader("File Upload - Uploading a file");
if (
    $client_id == '**********'
    || $client_secret == '**********'
    || $redirect_uri == '**********') {
  echo missingClientSecretsWarning();
}
?>
<div class="box">
  <div class="request">
    <?php if (isset($authUrl)): ?>
      <a class='login' href='<?php echo $authUrl; ?>'>Connect Me!</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>

  <?php if (isset($result) && $result): ?>
    <div class="shortened">
      <?php var_dump($result); ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif ?>
</div>
<?php
echo pageFooter(__FILE__);
```

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. A parent folder to what? Also, try to trim down your example to only relevant code.

Comment: There are several examples of this code, but libraries changed. En the documentation didn't change. So I put the hole code here. I like to put the uploaded files to a folder in my Google drive. Now it's in the root. I tried several codes for upload to a parent folder in my Google drive, but it didn't match. Look at the part of 'Set the parent folder'.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer for the parent option...

```
//Set the parent folder

$parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference(); 
$parentId='**********';
$parent->setId($parentId); 
$file->setParents(array($parent));
```